# Image Processing with Raspicam and C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to do basic image processing with the c++ library RaspiCam, but I saw there's not much information about usage with C++ out there.
Are there any good basic image processing libraries out there?
Basically what I want to do is take a picture with the Raspberry Pi Camera Module and read the colour-values (green, red, blue) of single pixels.
The only row of pixels I want to read out though is the last row of pixels, let's say my image format is 1280x720. My goal is to read all the pixel of the last row, meaning pixel 1/720, 2/720, 3/720 (not sure if that's the right way to explain it). There's a really good example code of a C-project which you can find right here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/image-processing/first.html
and that's exactly what I'm trying to do with C++.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For image processing/manipulation in C++ I recommend OpenCV. (http://opencv.org/) It is a computer vision library, and for your purpose it might be on the heavy side, but it is well-documented and stable.

Here is a tutorial on looping over pixels of an image using OpenCV: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html